# How to properly index a big matrix in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a big numpy array with certain entries. Let's say a dummy example is:

```
    arr = np.array([[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0],[1.5, 1.8, 3.2]],
                    [[1.3, 1.7, 1.9],[1.4, 1.9, 2.1]],
                    [[1.8, 2.2, 2.5],[2.0, 2.2, 2.8]]])
```

I would like to know all the indexes where the entries of `arr` fall within some range, say `1.5` and `2.4`. And I would like to fill another matrix of the same shape as `arr` with `1` at indexes where value of `arr` falls within the range, otherwise with `0`. That is, I would like to get a matrix like:

```
mask = np.array([[[0, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]],
                 [[0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 1]],
                 [[1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0]]])
```

Is there any simple `numpy` trick to do this? I know it is straightforward to do it with a `for loop`, but since my `arr` is pretty big in size, I would want it to be reasonably fast. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use masking and [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html): First create a conditional mask combining your two boundary conditions and then pass it to `np.where`. The matrix will be assigned `1` where this condition holds True else `0` if its False

**Minimal working answer**

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0],[1.5, 1.8, 3.2]],
                [[1.3, 1.7, 1.9],[1.4, 1.9, 2.1]],
                [[1.8, 2.2, 2.5],[2.0, 2.2, 2.8]]])

mask = ((arr>1.5) & (arr<2.4))
arr = np.where(mask, 1, 0)
print (arr)
```

**Output**

```
array([[[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[1, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 0]]])
```

Comment: Or `mask.astype(int)`.

Comment: @hpaulj: Thanks for the comment. could you please explain more what you mean? How exactly to use your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Create a boolean mask meeting your conditions.
Adding 0 to boolean values will convert them to numeric results:

```
import numpy as np

arr = np.array([[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0],[1.5, 1.8, 3.2]],
                [[1.3, 1.7, 1.9],[1.4, 1.9, 2.1]],
                [[1.8, 2.2, 2.5],[2.0, 2.2, 2.8]]])

arr_out = ((arr>=1.5) & (arr<=2.4)) + 0
print(arr_out)
```

Alternatively:

```
arr_out = np.array(((arr>=1.5) & (arr<=2.4)), dtype=np.uint8)
print(arr_out)
```

Or, as suggested by @hpaulj:

```
arr_out = ((arr>=1.5) & (arr<=2.4)).astype(int)
print (arr_out)
```

Output:

```
[[[0 1 0]
  [1 1 0]]

 [[0 1 1]
  [0 1 1]]

 [[1 1 0]
  [1 1 0]]]
```